# Rotate original Image with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Hello my doubts today is how can I rotate a photo, say no to just turn rotate the photo in a browser but doing a photo that was taken in portrait and landscape stand in different angles to really change the picture, and all this with Jquery or JavaScript someone there to help?

### JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/291](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/291/)

```
var look = false;

//**************************************************************************************
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var angleInDegrees = 0;
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image, canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - image.width / 2);
}
image.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";
//**************************************************************************************
var photoTwo = document.getElementById("photoTwo");
var ctxTwo = photoTwo.getContext("2d");
var angleInDegreesTwo = 0;
var imageTwo = document.createElement("img");
imageTwo.onload = function () {
    ctxTwo.drawImage(imageTwo, photoTwo.width / 2 - imageTwo.width / 2, photoTwo.height / 2 - imageTwo.width / 2);
}
imageTwo.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";
//**************************************************************************************

$("#clockwise").click(function () {
    look = true;
    angleInDegrees += 90;
    drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
});

$("#counterclockwise").click(function () {
    look = false;
    angleInDegrees += 90;
    drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
});

function drawRotated(degrees) {
    var tmp_canvas;
    var tmp_ctx;
    var tmp_img;
    if (look) {
        tmp_canvas = canvas;
        tmp_ctx = ctx;
        tmp_img = image;
    } else {
        tmp_canvas = photoTwo;
        tmp_ctx = ctxTwo;
        tmp_img = imageTwo;
    }

    tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
    tmp_ctx.save();
    tmp_ctx.translate(tmp_canvas.width / 2, tmp_canvas.height / 2);
    tmp_ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    tmp_ctx.drawImage(tmp_img, -tmp_img.width / 2, -tmp_img.width / 2);
    tmp_ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is all about showing what you have tried, with examples etc, then asking for help with specific *programming* problems. Please do a little research then ask specific questions.

Comment: here's what I tried to do after that have to get the image in base64, but does not work out this page: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/291/

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS...? That's all that jquery is going to do for you?

Comment: using css the image will not change in the presentation to the User, the original image will not be altered Quere I rotate the original image, if I save the rotated with css in a pdf using jspdf in pdf image the image will not appear rotated, I I want to save the rotated in pdf image using jspdf, why css will not be useful because it only changes the presentation and not the actual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you wish to rotate canvas and keep the canvas the same size as the image when rotated** (for example if you want to save out the image etc.) then you can simply set the canvas size for each time you rotate it.

A simple way of doing this is to store 90 degree increments in an array and use the index of the current angle of that array to determine what size (landscape /portrait) the canvas should be.

Sounds complicated? It's really simple:

```
/// store angles (0, 90, 180, 270) in an array
var angles = [0 * Math.PI, 0.5 * Math.PI, Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI],
    index = 0;
```

Now we have pre-calculated angles and the first angle is the originally orientation.

After the image has loaded we simply draw the image at whatever index we have, but we use the index to set the landscape/portrait mode by simply setting the canvas = image size if 0 or 180 degrees, and opposite for 90 and 270 degrees, ie, canvas height = image width and canvas width = image height.

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Hq7p2/)

This makes sure the canvas is equal the size and orientation of the image when rotated.

```
function renderImage() {

    /// use index to set canvas size
    switch(index) {
        case 0:
        case 2:
            /// for 0 and 180 degrees size = image
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 3:
            /// for 90 and 270 canvas width = img height etc.
            canvas.width = img.height;
            canvas.height = img.width;
            break;
    }

    /// get stored angle and center of canvas    
    var angle = angles[index],
        cw = canvas.width * 0.5,
        ch = canvas.height * 0.5;
    
    /// rotate context
    ctx.translate(cw, ch);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(-img.width * 0.5, -img.height * 0.5);
    
    /// draw image and reset transform
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

To rotate the image just hook of the following code to the buttons:

```
/// rotate counter-clock-wise (CCW)
function rotateCCW() {
    index--;      /// decrement index of array
    if (index < 0) index = angles.length -1;
    renderImage();
}

/// rotate clock-wise (CW)
function rotateCW() {
    index++;     /// increment index of array
    if (index >= angles.length) index = 0;
    renderImage();
}
```

Comment: would like to know is how to get the image in base64 without using a server?

Comment: @Vanessa just use `var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL()` to get a base-64 encoded data uri (or string) of the image.

Comment: but he only returns if a server is not? I like to run it off a server is to?

Comment: @Vanessa all this happens at client side without any server involved (provided the page is already loaded into client from somewhere and the image is available - the code itself do not depend on server). Hope this helps!

Comment: when I run the html page outside the server or it loads the image, and when I try to get the image for the toDataURL it the following error. 

"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement':. Tainted canvases may not be exported" 

but you are helping me a lot ^ ^

Comment: @Vanessa this is because the image is loaded from a different origin (f.ex domain) and security will prevent you from extracting pixels from canvas in that case. Make sure the image is loaded from the same origin as the page or configure the external server to allow cross-origin use. See for example [this for more details](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-use-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-with-canvas/). Please consider accepting/upvoting answer. For other questions please open a new question/post unless they are directly related to original question.