# Scaling the image and fitting in the canvas after rotation

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to rotate an image and fit it in the canvas using button clicks.

I could fit the image to canvas size initially but when I rotate the image, it is going back to its original size and only a part of the image is seen in the canvas. How can I fit the image to canvas even while rotating.

I have seen an example on SO by [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834275/having-some-problems-rotating-an-image-inside-a-canvas) but when the image size is bigger, the canvas is scaling to the size of image. I need the canvas size to be constant and the image size to scale accordingly while rotating and when loaded. I tried to modify the code by trying two different answers by `markE` but couldn't achieve it.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLyou41j/2/)

Comment: By the way, wow, that vertical farm is cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated JS fiddle link -

https://jsfiddle.net/oLyou41j/3/

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var currentDegrees=0;

var image=document.createElement("img");
image.src="http://b.static.trunity.net/files/299501_299600/299598/vertical-farming-chris-jacobs.jpg";
image.onload=function(){
//Remove extra lines                
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.height, canvas.width);
}


$("#clockwise").click(function(){ 
currentDegrees+=90;
drawRotated(currentDegrees);
});

$("#counterclockwise").click(function(){ 
   currentDegrees-=90;
drawRotated(currentDegrees);
});

function drawRotated(degrees){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);

//Changed Method
ctx.drawImage(image,-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2, canvas.height, canvas.width);
ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ayush for the updated solution. But is there any way we can keep the aspect fit instead of fill in this solution?

Comment: Check my other answer

Answer (score 1):

JS fiddle link, if you want to have aspect fit as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/oLyou41j/4/

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var currentDegrees=0;

var image=document.createElement("img");
image.onload=function(){
                    var wrh = image.width / image.height;
        var newWidth = canvas.width;
        var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
        if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
            newHeight = canvas.height;
            newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
        }
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,newWidth,newHeight);
}
image.src="http://b.static.trunity.net/files/299501_299600/299598/vertical-farming-chris-jacobs.jpg";

$("#clockwise").click(function(){ 
currentDegrees+=90;
drawRotated(currentDegrees);
});

$("#counterclockwise").click(function(){ 
currentDegrees-=90;
drawRotated(currentDegrees);
});

function drawRotated(degrees){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    var wrh = image.width / image.height;
        var newWidth = canvas.width;
        var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
        if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
            newHeight = canvas.height;
            newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
        }
ctx.drawImage(image,-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2,newWidth,newHeight);

ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ayush for the solution. Is there any way I can load and rotate the image along the center of canvas? If I'm not wrong, before c`ctx.draw` I need to translate the image to center and draw the image and then rotate along the center of canvas? Is my understanding correct?